# Mystic Ally becomes useless in inferno acts 2 and above?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

Just wondering whether any monks still use the Mystic Ally skill for acts 2 and up?

I am guessing that most of you will say that it wastes a slot for a defensive skill. I don't use blind yet (i know noooooooob :p) but will try that tonight to replace my earth ally.

Answer (score 1):

Mystic Ally (especially Earth Ally) can be useful for absorbing ranged attacks (from those nasty wasps' bugs, hellflayers, shamans, etc.), drawing an elite or two away so you can focus down one of them, and acting as a scout/decoy so can get an idea of what nasty surprises up ahead.

They are also nice for blocking enemies in narrow spaces like doors and stairways, drawing elite spawned traps like arcane sentries away from you. Earth Ally gives you an extra 10% HP and can tank decently (taunts). I believe Earth Ally also scales with your gear.

Unfortunately, they aren't very smart and do things like scaring off treasure goblins and attacking invulnerable enemies.

Answer (score 1):

The mystic Earth ally is great to have on boss fights when playing with a friend.  The forced aggro is extremely handy when you need to run off and resurrect a downed ally.  Comes in real handy on bosses, even Inferno Diablo.

Answer (score 1):

It honestly depends on your skill build and current stats. With a higher DPS weapon, I've found the Water Ally and Fire Ally to dish out a decent amount of damage before dying, especially when running a 2h test build. However, various elite affixes pose large problems for the ally.

I would suggest staying away from Earth Ally, in particular. While the health boost and tanking are quite useful, it typically dies before it's situationally needed.

Answer (score 1):

I put Earth Ally on my set not because of damage output but it really helps with my survivability. HP boosts is also a plus.

Let my Earth Ally isolates one champion of from their pack make I finish them faster.
When it is 1-1 fight, decoying is mostly effective.

Completely agree with above guys but dont have enough reps to vote.